# Modular exponentiation in astronomical large power [closed]

Tags: nt.number-theory

$x_1^{x_2^{x_3}}$ mod $M$ = ?, where $x_i$ and $M$ - integers

Exponentiation by squaring isn't fast enough.

Example:
[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=113317^202000^102007+mod+622301](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=113317%5E202000%5E102007+mod+622301)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I think it is a request for an algorithm. So, to the person asking: are you actually doing this or are you just curious? 

Comment: I guess you want $113317^{202000^{102007}}$ modulo 622301. Well, do the inner exponentiation modulo $\phi(622301)$...

Comment: @Will Jagy Sorry. I need fast algorithm to compute such expressions.
@Junkie How it will be fast (asymptotically)? I need to calculate it for a few seconds.

Comment: @stranger: Just try first $202000^{102007}$ modulo $\phi(622301)=622300$. 1 second computation (in GP-Pari) gives 86500. Then $113317^{86500}\equiv151627$ modulo 622301 takes another second. Isn't it fast enough?!

Comment: @Wadim: Perhaps stranger is asking for large composite $M$'s, in which case $\phi(M)$ is a nontrivial computation. I can't think of a quick way that doesn't involve factoring $M$.

Comment: The $M$ should be indeed large (at least about 40 decimal digits) in order to cause the factoring problem. But then there is no way to do the exponentiation fast. I believe that he was simply stuck with his example, and indeed without the inner exponentiation I get (in GP-Pari) *stack overflow*.

Comment: @Wadim Zudilin: wow! That is what i'm looking for. Thanks! And where i can find explanation of that?

Comment: @stranger: All that is due to Euler. He showed that $a^{\phi(m)}\equiv1\pmod m$ for $a$ coprime with $m$. This implies that $a^x\equiv a^{x\pmod{\phi(m)}}\pmod m$ and gives you the grounds of the double exponentiation. I am sorry to see that your question is closed. But I hope that you are satisfied by the knowledge you now have.

Comment: @Wadim Zudilin: Thank you for explanation!